# Обновление пользовательского лога в JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте.

В приложении веду лог для пользователя в JTextArea,а JTextArea в JScrollPane.Как можно обновлять его чтобы он не сползал как при `scrollPane.update();` и не было мерцания как при `frame.update(frame.getGraphics());`?

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот набросал пример в соответствии с вашим описанием. При нажатии на кнопку обновить добавляется текст в JTextArea.

```
public class TestFrame1 extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame1() throws HeadlessException {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton(new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.append("\r\nstr str str");
            }
        });
        btn.setText("Обновить");

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(btn,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new TestFrame1();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```